# P value validity

Tags: permutation, p-value

I have done a statistical analysis in DNA methylation data, I already wrote my report, but it got rejected by my adviser as he wants me to do some changes in the paper.

One question I couldn't answer because I didn't really understand it was related to the p value.

During the analysis I ran a permutation test using a code I wrote in R where samples were shuffled 1000 times, and calculated the p value. But my professor asked me "How to know the validity of p-value. What was the error model?"

I wasn't able to respond because i didn't know what he really meant, but I was reading about the permutation test recently and couldn't get an answer yet.

Can anyone help me understanding this question, please?

Comment: You can probably get a better answer by posting this question (if it has not been posted already) here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Permutation tests are always valid as long as your null was specified correct. That is, your case and control samples are all iid under the null. To validate this, you can probably look at your DNA methylation data under some empirical null model (e.g., calculate the p-value on two comparison groups both without any methylation). Under the null, the p-value should be uniformly distributed, which can be confirmed by looking at the QQ plot. But I would also suggest directly asking your professors regarding what he meant.